# How do i extract data from a live website with python?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, raspberry-pi

I am wondering on how i will extract live data from a website with python.
Here is the link to the website: https://live.alphatiming.co.uk/24hr

Comment: SO you want it realtime?

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML and your code trials

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve] for guidance on posting questions that elicit quality answers that benefit you and future readers and that make your question searchable/more useful to future readers.

Comment: This looks like a good candidate for the newish MutationObserver API, but unfortunately I don't think it plays well with selenium. You will have to poll the browser context instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see in the Network, that page makes a GET call to this URL: https://live.alphatiming.co.uk/24hr.json in order to get the data.

The easiest way, in this case, is to use `requests` to reproduce and just parse the json:

```
import requests

response = requests.get(url='https://live.alphatiming.co.uk/24hr.json').json()
print(response) # This will print out the data coming from that endpoint
```

To get the data you are looking for, just work with response as with a dict. For example:

```
# print only Competitors data:
print(response['Competitors'])
# print out list with the names of teams:
print([competitor['CompetitorName'] for competitor in response['Competitors']])
```

Comment: How to make this `request` infinite loop? For getting the live data? put the response part in a while loop?

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at the website that you linked in your question and was kinda satisfied watching those dots on track and the progress bar (don't know why).

However, I think that `requests` and `beautifulsoup` will do the job, just look at the tags from where you want data from.

make the script for that how to extract that data.

then either use a task scheduling website and hit the api (you code which may be hosted on heroku).

have a look at [this](https://cron-job.org/en/) pretty intuitive. 
or as your tags suggests use `RasberryPI` as a server for scheduling a task which runs your script every 2-3 sec.

i hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests

s = requests.Session()
url = 'https://live.alphatiming.co.uk/24hr'
page = s.get(url).text

print(page)
```

Comment: That will only get you data from the initial pageload, not the live data asked for in the question, which is dynamically generated after pageload.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.